# Redirecting after login with successful $authWithOAuthRedirect in Firebase / Angularfire

Tags: angularjs, oauth, firebase, angular-ui-router, angularfire

According to the [AngularFire Auth API](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/api.html#angularfire-users-and-authentication-authwithoauthredirectprovider-options), `$authWithOAuthRedirect` should return a promise that's resolved after returning to your app. I've created the factory below, but the promise in `login()` doesn't seem to resolve following a successful authorisation; nothing gets logged to the console. So `$state.go()` isn't firing, and the user doesn't get redirected to the `app` state.

```
(function (angular) {

    'use strict';

    var module = angular.module('app');

    module.factory('AuthFactory', [
        '$firebaseAuth',
        '$state',
        'Config',
        function ($firebaseAuth, $state, Config) {

            var ref = new Firebase(Config.firebase.api);
            var FirebaseAuth = $firebaseAuth(ref);

            FirebaseAuth.login = function () {
                return this.$authWithOAuthRedirect('google')
                    .then(function (authData) {
                        console.log('Logged in as:', authData.uid, authData);
                        $state.go('app');
                    })
                    .catch(function (error) {
                        console.error('Authentication failed:', error);
                    });
            }.bind(FirebaseAuth);

            return FirebaseAuth;
        }
    ]);

}(window.angular));
```

If I log `$getAuth` in the controller, I can see the login's worked once I do a refresh. So can anyone shed any light on why it's not redirecting as expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The promise returned from `authWithOAuthRedirect()` is a bit misleading, in that it will never be fulfilled. Because the browser will redirect away from the page, we can never actually invoke the promise because the state of the page has been lost on successful redirection.

If you're on a page of your app that you'd like to automatically redirect when the user is logged-in, try `ref.onAuth(function(authData) { ... })`. The `authData` will be non-null if the user is logged-in.

Comment: I thought that was the case, I thought I might just be missing something! Thanks - accepted answer.